# Compile code based on which version of Visual Studio you are using with .Net

Tags: c#, compilation, macros

Is there a way to detect Visual Studio version via a macro or code? (C#)

I'm trying to maintain a repository whose codebase is written in C# where users are using both VS2015/VS2019.  So far I have figured out various workarounds to maintain it without maintaining multiple branches.  However, I need to check what version of Visual Studio they are using dynamically so they don't have to define a macro manually after downloading the project from the repository. (or changing it every time someone using the other visual studio version changes the codebase)

There is a _MSC_VER for C/C++, but I haven't figured out how to set a macro based on this number (if i can even use it), as conditional macros don't work in C# like they do in C/C++.

Ideally I'd like a macro that can check _MSC_VER like:

```
#if ( _MSC_VER > 1919 )
//mycode
#endif
```

Currently, my solution is to have the user manually define a VS2015 or VS2019 macro which is not ideal like so:

```
#define VS2019
//...
#if (VS2019)
    //code
#endif
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `#if NET47
          
#endif`.

Comment: Both versions of Visual Studio are targeting the same framework, I'm looking to differentiate based on the version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Got it. Actually I thought, though you have mentioned `VS` but meant to framework.  Predefined symbols not available for VS.  May I know what is actual purpose. Accordingly we can decide.

Comment: Its because pathing ends up being different in the version of VS I've been using.  I've fixed it up using 
 <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath> 

in the 2019 version, and now the projects only differ at a .csproj level, so its not needed to change in code.  For now, this solution satisfies the need for the user to not have to modify anything after downloading from repo.

Still interested in how to do it programatically, so I'll leave this open for a while though, because I might need it in the future if other things differ by VS version.

Comment: I think provided your need the only possible way to define a symbol for `VS version` in `Conditional compilation symbols` field of `build` tab. If you have different project for different VS you can use it. Otherwise you need to create another build configuration.

Comment: The closest thing to this is probably the [`MSBuildToolsVersion` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion) set by MSBuild -- this can be used to conditionally define a preprocessor symbol that your project can check (or just directly in the project). However -- if there are actual differences in how your project builds depending on tool version, there is probably something wrong with your build (as in, that variance should either not exist, or it should be handled through something other than checking on the VS/MSBuild version).